# JSF 2.0: Empty operator doesn't work with param

Tags: java, jsf-2, el, param

In the file `aPage.xhtml`, I have the following lines:

```
<ui:include rendered="#{not empty param.target}" src="#{param.target}.html" />
<ui:include rendered="#{empty param.target}" src="About.html" />
```

With the above lines, I expected that when I go to `http://localhost:8080/beta/aPage.xhtml`, the page `About.html` would be included since the `param.target` is `null`. However, GlassFish threw me the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/beta/.html
```

Somehow, `param.target` was not considered to be `null`.

Besides, I did try to use `==` and `!=` operators as following:

```
<ui:include rendered="#{param.target != null}" src="#{param.target}.html" />
<ui:include rendered="#{param.target == null}" src="About.html" />
```

Interestingly, this time, on the console of GlassFish, I didn't see any exception thrown. However, on the browser, an error page still appears with the exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

I'd be very grateful if you could tell me why this happened and what I should do to avoid it.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the hint from Joop Eggen, I finally solved the problem with the following  lines:

```
<ui:param name="noTarget"  value="About.html" />
<ui:param name="hasTarget" value="#{param.target}.html" />
<ui:include src="#{empty param.target? noTarget : hasTarget}" />
```

Best regards

Comment: `param.target` seems to hold the `-en` value , which means its not empty and that's why you are refered to `-en.html` page... seems that there an issue with the value that being hold by `param.target`

Comment: @Daniel: oops, sorry, the `-en` should not be there. I missed that when I was simplifying my code for posting here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The src is evaluated in both cases, maybe with a file existence test? Do

```
<ui:include src="#{empty param.target? 'About' : param.target}.html" />
```

Comment: You can't use `+` to concatenate strings in EL. I fixed the syntax.

Comment: @BalusC , say why does my proposed solutio does not work in this scenario ? cause it always works just fine for me...

Comment: @Daniel: EL in `src` of `<ui:include>` is evaluated during view build time, not during view render time. It works only if the `src` points a valid path.

Answer (score 3):

`ui:include` got no `rendered` attribute... wrap it with `<h:panelGroup`

like this

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty param.target}">
   <ui:include  src="#{param.target}.html" />
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty param.target}" >
    <ui:include src="About.html" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

**Edit**

Unfortunately this will work only when EL in src of  points a valid path ,

cause

> EL in src of `<ui:include>` is evaluated during view build time, not during view render time

Comment: Even though NetBeans suggested that `ui:include` has `rendered` attribute, it seems that you may be right. However, I still run into the same exception using your solution.

Comment: try to output the param.target in your page... what does it show you? `<h:outputText value="prefix#{param.target}suffix"/>` do you see anything between prefix and suffix ?

Comment: I did try to replace `<ui:include>` with `<h:outputText>` in your above code. It printed out the correct message when `param.target` is null and not null. I think Joop Eggen is right. The `src` attribute was evaluated in both cases.

Comment: I always use the wrapping with `h:panelGroup` and it always worked here... I wonder if <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param.target eq ''}" and <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param.target ne ''}"  or with null would work..

Comment: As I told you, I tried to put `<h:outputText value="Empty">` inside `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty param.target}" >` and it worked perfectly. The problem only occurs if I put `<ui:include>` inside the `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty param.target}" >`. :)